# How to put the 5x5 grid of images in whole page in a conference paper IEEEtran format

Tags: graphics, floats, ieeetran

[image: But I get this because the page is split into two sections.]
I want something like the above

[image: I want something like this]
But I get this because the page is split into two sections.

Can anyone please help me with this?
I tried the following both of which won't put the image in a whole page:

```
enter code here
-------Option 1------------
\begin{figure}[htp]

\centering
\includegraphics[width=.1\textwidth]{images/T1_W5.png}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.1\textwidth]{images/T1_W9.png}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.1\textwidth]{images/T1_W11.png}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.1\textwidth]{images/T1_W15.png}\hfill

\caption{default}
\label{fig:figure3}

\end{figure}
-----------Option 2-----
\begin{figure}

\begin{tabular}{cccc}
{\includegraphics[width = .5in]{T1.png}} &
{\includegraphics[width = .75in]{T2.png}} &
{\includegraphics[width = .7in]{T3.png}} &
{\includegraphics[width = .7in]{T4.png}}&\\
{\includegraphics[width = .5in]{T1.png}} &
{\includegraphics[width = .75in]{T2.png}} &
{\includegraphics[width = .7in]{T3.png}} &
{\includegraphics[width = .7in]{T4.png}}&

\end{tabular}
\caption{Input Images}

\end{figure}
```

```
\begin{figure*}[p]

\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\subfloat[a ]{\includegraphics[width = 0.6in]{T1.png}} &
{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/T1_W5.png}} &
{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/T1_W9.png}} &
{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/T1_W11.png}}&
{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/T1_W15.png}} &\\
{\includegraphics[width = 0.6in]{T2.png}} &
{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/T2_W5.png}} &
{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/T2_W9.png}} &
{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/T2_W11.png}}&
{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/T2_W15.png}} &\\
{\includegraphics[width = 0.6in]{T3.png}} &
{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/T3_W5.png}} &
{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/T3_W9.png}} &
{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/T3_W11.png}}&
{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/T3_W15.png}} &\\
{\includegraphics[width = 0.6in]{T4.png}} &
{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/T4_W5.png}} &
{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/T4_W9.png}} &
{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/T4_W11.png}}&
{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/T4_W15.png}} &\\
{\includegraphics[width = 0.6in]{T5.png}} &
{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/T5_W5.png}} &
{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/T5_W9.png}} &
{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/T5_W11.png}}&
{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/T5_W15.png}} &\\

\end{tabular}
\caption{Input Images}

\end{figure*}
```

The above code works but is there a way to shorten it? also label the leftmost image? [image]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! by use of `figure*: `\begin{figure*}{p}` . for image inside you need to inform us, if you like tu have all as subimages. the best way to receive some answer is to show, what you tray so far.

Comment: @Zarko I didn't understand

Comment: @Zarko I think your idea works I have to add \begin{figure*} but how this works? Will you please let me know or point to any source?

Comment: what you not understand? actally what is your problem? instead of code fragment, please provide complete small document, which we can copy and test in our computers (beginning with `\documentclass{...}` preamble, some dummy text and your figure and end with `\end{figure}`. as i conclude from your question, your figure should occupay whole page,. to do this you should use `\begin{figure*}[p] ... your images ... \end{figure*}˙. on this way figure will be over both columns. `p` stabd for `page`, meaning that on page will be only figure.

Comment: @Zarko How to share the entire code? Your solution works, now I need to caption the images like as they did in the first image.

Comment: @Zarko But now I have figure floating issue. The figure was supposed to come in section1 but it goes to the end of the page. Any solution for that?

Comment: @Zarko https://www.overleaf.com/7131326917bwxfkvrhnrcv
 Let me know if you can access the link it has the original files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see if the following MWE can help you:

**edit:**

simpler is to use `tabularx` table environment than `tabular` (since it perform column width calculation itself). now MWE contain grid 5 x 5 images.

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{stfloats} % for positioning of figure* on the same page
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[b]
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=\\linewidth}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} p{1em}p{0.5in} *{4}{X} @{}}
a)  & \includegraphics[height=0.5in]{T1.png}
    & \includegraphics{T2.png}
    & \includegraphics{T3.png}
    & \includegraphics{T4.png}
    & \includegraphics{T5.png}    \\
b)  & \includegraphics[height=0.5in]{T1.png}
    & \includegraphics{T2.png}
    & \includegraphics{T3.png}
    & \includegraphics{T4.png}
    & \includegraphics{T5.png}    \\
c)  & \includegraphics[height=0.5in]{T1.png}
    & \includegraphics{T2.png}
    & \includegraphics{T3.png}
    & \includegraphics{T4.png}
    & \includegraphics{T5.png}    \\
d)  & \includegraphics[height=0.5in]{T1.png}
    & \includegraphics{T2.png}
    & \includegraphics{T3.png}
    & \includegraphics{T4.png}
    & \includegraphics{T5.png}    \\
e)  & \includegraphics[height=0.5in]{T1.png}
    & \includegraphics{T2.png}
    & \includegraphics{T3.png}
    & \includegraphics{T4.png}
    & \includegraphics{T5.png}    \\
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Input Images}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

**note:** `figure*` can be placed only on the top of the next page from where is inserted in text. with use of the package `stfloats` is possible to place image on the bottom of the page, if there is enough place for it.

Comment: The problem is image goes to the end of the page. Instead of coming to section 1. I'm updating the image of the issue in the original question.

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/7131326917bwxfkvrhnrcv - Let me know if you access this link.

Comment: @RaghavendraSS, see added note to my answer.